# MIPS Searching an array, with stack implemented

Tags: arrays, search, assembly, stack, mips

So this comes from Exercise 6.2 of the book MIPS Assembly Language Programming, by Britton. I need to use a byte size array with 10 preset integers, prompt the system to ask the user to enter a number to search for. If the number is found, print the element at which it is stored, if not found print a different message. I need to do this using the stack, which is were I believe I am getting my error. I am almost positive its in the stack, but I have tried everything that I can think of. Any suggestions would be extremely appreciated. Thanks! Here is my code so far:

Solved: Code has been updated.

```js
X:  .byte  1, 27, 92, 46, 72, 8, 13, 93, 65, 112
N:  .word 10
srch: .asciiz "Please enter a number to search for: "
posi: .asciiz "That numbers location is in element "
fals: .asciiz "That number is not in the array."
nxln: .asciiz "\n"

 .text

main:         la $s0, X
 la   $s1, N
 
 la  $a0, srch
 li  $v0, 4
 syscall
 li  $v0, 5
 syscall
 move         $t2, $v0
 
 addiu          $sp, $sp, -24 # stack prep
 sw  $s0, 0($sp)
 sb  $s1, 4($sp)
 sb  $t2, 8($sp)
 jal  search
 lb  $t2, 12($sp)
 lb  $t3, 16($sp)
 
 addiu         $sp, $sp, 24
 
 la  $a0, posi
 li  $v0, 4
 syscall
 li  $v0, 1
 move         $a0, $t2
 syscall
 
 li  $v0, 10
 syscall
 
search: 
 lw  $t5, 0($sp) # get &X
 lb  $t8, 4($sp) # get N
 lb  $t7, 8($sp) # get V
 move $t6, $t8
 addi $t6, $t6, -1  # $t6 = N - 1
loop: 
 lb  $t4, 0($t5) # get a character (always get my error here)
 addi         $t5, $t5, 1 # increment pointer
 beq  $t4, $t7, found
 addi         $t6, $t6, -1 # decrement loop counter
 bgez         $t6, loop
 li  $t4, -1
 sw   $t4, 16($sp)
 b  exit
found:
 sub  $t6, $t6, $t8
 sb  $t6, 12($sp)
 jr  $ra
exit: 
 la  $a0, fals
 li  $v0, 4
 syscall
 li  $v0, 10
 syscall
```

Comment: You use `lb` to load `$t5`, but that is a pointer which is not a single byte but a word and thus needs `lw`. Also you used `sb` to set it up from `$s0`, that's similarly wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed it. Can't believe I overlooked that.